# Python keyword output interpretation

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword

I'm going through the Python 2.7 tutorial, and I was looking at the output of the following statement:

```
def cheeseshop(kind, *arguments, **keywords):
    print "-- Do you have any", kind, "?"
    print "-- I'm sorry, we're all out of", kind
    for arg in arguments:
        print arg
    print "-" * 40
    keys = sorted(keywords.keys())
    for kw in keys:
        print kw, ":", keywords[kw]
```

So, if I call the program as such:

```
cheeseshop("Cheddar", "No.", "Seriously?",
       Shopkeeper="Michael Palin",
       Client="John Cleese")
```

It outputs:

```
Do you have any Cheddar?
I'm sorry, we're all out of Cheddar
No.
Seriously?
--------------------------------------
Client: John Cleese
Shopkeeper: Michael Palin
```

This is correct.

If I change that print statement to `print keywords`, I get the following representation:

```
{'Shopkeeper': 'Ryan Lambert', 'Client': 'John Cleese'}
```

I'm a bit confused on how printing `keywords[kw]` just comes back with a name, and `keywords` does not.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please clarify.

Comment: keywords is a dictionary. keywords[kw] is a value of the keyword dictionary and kw is a key from that dictionary as well. So when you "print keywords", you get the full representation of the dictionary, not just names.

Comment: you are a bit confused about dictionaries in python?

Comment: njzk2 - yes, I think so. I'm missing something. dilbert - so, keywords[kw] is actually referencing a value, and not a key? ie: keywords[kw] is synonymous with keywords.values()?

Comment: keywords[kw] is synonymous with a SINGLE element of the list that is keywords.values().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In Python, you can pass optional keyword parameters by putting a `**` in front of the function parameter's list.](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html)

So the `keywords` variable is actually a dictionary type.  Thus, if you do:

```
print keywords
```

you get back (reformatted to make the mapping more obvious)

```
{
    'Shopkeeper': 'Ryan Lambert', 
    'Client': 'John Cleese'
}
```

which is a dictionary.  And if you do:

```
print keywords[kw]
```

you get back the value of the dictionary associated with the key `kw`.  So if `kw` was `'Shopkeeper'`, then `keywords[kw]` becomes `'Ryan Lambert'`, and if `kw` was `'Client'`, then `keywords[kw]` becomes `'John Cleese'`

Comment: Ahhhh... okay. This makes sense. This is the part I was missing. Thank you. :) Sorry the question was a little garbled... I wasn't sure how to phrase it without being overly verbose.

Comment: No problem.  Hope this clarifies!

Answer (score 0):

keywords is stored as a *dictionary*. ( See [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for more)

If you print the dictionary itself it is going to output the complete set of pairs it contains (key,value).

On your program:

- keys are: 'Shopkeeper' and 'Client'
- values are respectively: 'Ryan Lambert' and 'John Cleese'

One way to access the values is to "search" for it with its key: dict[key]

So when you wrote: "keywords[kw]" you are actually passing a key and python is going to give you the corresponding value.

You can think it as similar as accessing an array value:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

if you:

```
print a #output: ['a', 'b', 'c']    
print a[0] # outputs: 'a'
```

just unlike arrays the data is not stored "neatly" together in memory, but using hashing

Hope it helped, Cheers

Comment: No problem! Dictionaries are really useful, but be aware when to use them and when arrays are better (performance, size, etc)

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function with

```
cheeseshop("Cheddar", "No.", "Seriously?",
           Shopkeeper="Michael Palin", Client="John Cleese")
```

the `keywords` parameter takes on the value `{'Shopkeeper': 'Ryan Lambert', 'Client': 'John Cleese'}`, i.e., it's a dictionary.

This is equivalent to (and much easier to read than) calling the function as

```
cheeseshop("Cheddar", *["No.", "Seriously?"],
           **{"Shopkeeper":"Michael Palin", "Client":"John Cleese"})
```

That is, the values in the first function call are automatically wrapped inside the `*arguments` and  `**keywords` parameters -- that's what those `*` and `**` are for.

Now, when you do this:

```
keys = sorted(keywords.keys())
for kw in keys:
    print kw, ":", keywords[kw]
```

`keyword.keys()` is `['Shopkeeper', 'Client']`, i.e. the "keys" in the dictionary. Next, you sort those keys and for each key, you print the respective entry in the dictionary, e.g., "John Cleese" for "Client".